# A word for when a machine or process occasionally misses a step

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a verb that means that a process misses a step occasionally.

This would be for a case where a machine or process sometimes, but not always, produces incorrect results. For programming code this is not necessarily because of a logical bug in the code, but because of e.g. the software application not working optimally in the OS environment it is used in. For physical machines this could probably happen because of some tolerance of a lever or something like that.

Is there like a way to say that e.g. "the machine is [insert verb here]"

Comment: "Misfire", "hiccup", "miss a beat".

Comment: @HotLicks These sound like answers to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"stutter"   ..................

Comment: No; stuttering does not exactly match the occasional missing of a beat. You'd need 'gave the occasional stutter'.

Comment: If it's a regular pattern, it's a _syncopated stutter_.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard people say that a system "[glitched](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/glitch?s=t)" when a normally reliable system produced an incorrect result. For your sentence, that would be "the machine is glitching." One definition of glitch is

> A sudden instance of malfunctioning or irregularity in an electronic
>   system

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the situations you describe are "intermittent" failures.

"The gears fail intermittently when used underwater."